# Can not set int field to null value

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have this `int` column:

```
@Column(length = 4)
private int contract_owner_id;
```

I don't need to set always value for every table row. I get this exception when I make select query:

```
Can not set int field org.entity.contracts.contract_owner_id to null value
```

Is there some way to set numb setups when there is no data into the table column?

Comment: Can you change `int` to `Integer` or `Long` please

Comment: Wha tis the difference in int and Integer when I use them with JPA?

Comment: int is a primitive type not an Object

Comment: Though int and Integer are used to store integer type data the major difference between both is type of int is primitive while Integer is of class type. So int can not be null.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The primitive datatype **int** isn't **nullable**. You need to use the Wrapper class `Integer` in this case. So just replace the type.

Comment: Is there some configuration that I can use to allow int to be null?

Comment: What di you mean?

Comment: @PeterPenzov please try the solution

Comment: @PeterPenzov int is not an object. So it can not be null.

Comment: The best way to avoid Hibernate's attempts at setting null values to primitives is to use Wrapper classes. Auto-boxing is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

use `Integer` instead of `int`

ex-:

`private Integer contract_owner_id;`

Answer (score 0):

Could be because you are using primitive datatype, try to use Wrapper instead (Long, Integer, Double)